# How do I display a bitmap image in my Wpf window using only XAML?

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have a blank window and i want a image in the center.I first tried dragging and dropping in the designer.Doesn't work.Then i tried an assortment of other examples on the internet.Couldn't get it to work either.one kinda worked but it wouldn't let me change the image's position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control in a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx):

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source=... Stretch="None" />
</Grid>
```